# Es correcto relacionar dos tablas muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos, modelorelacional

Buenas tardes me explico mejor

Es que me enfrento a un problema y la verdad no encuentro como solucionarlo y quiza sea sencillo o no. Al final de la tarde se me ha ocurrido relacionar dos tablas que han sido derivadas de un par de relaciones muchos a muchos.

*es decir*

**tabla1 y tabla2 (m:n)  = tabla3**---> relacion muchos a muchos uno

*luego necesito:*

**tabla1 y tabla1 (m:n)  = tabla4**  ----->  relación muchos a muchos esta deriva de una relación entre ella misma.

*lo que se ha ocurrido*

**tabla3 y tabla4  = tabla5**

Ahora bien necesito los datos de tabla3 y tabal4 en una sola tabla. Al relacionarlas me aparecería la tabla5 con todas las keys de tabla3 y tabla4

Así que mi pregunta es seria correcto relacionar muchos a muchos las dos tablas derivadas de otra relación muchos a muchos ?

es lo único que se me ha ocurrido a esta hora y por mas que doy vueltas no hallo una solución practica

Por favor si alguien pudiese darme una idea sobre esto se lo agradecería.

saludos

Comment: Para brindarte una mejor respuesta podrías compartir algo que ya hayas intentado? De esa manera y dependiendo el caso podríamos construir la mejor respuesta a tu problema.

Comment: Gracias Eliseo tienes razon ayer por el cansancio realmente no escribi mas nada
La cuestion es la siguiente tengo varios tipos de usuario en el sistema la cuestiones que necesito validar usuario1 usuario2 
ninguno comparte datos como tal entre si, pero ellos pueden enviar mensajerias entre ellos. El tema esta en que algunos de ellos tienen que tener un mail obligatorio otros no , asi que por eso no los pongo en una sola tabla y le defino role, porque tendria que poner.

usuario1 escribe a usuario2 

y usuario1 escribe a usuario1

Comment: Cuando el usuario1 entra en su panel y ve sus mensajes, encuentra el historial con los mensajes enviados a los usuario2 y a los usuarios1.

Entonces por ello he pensado que se crea una tabla de mensajes usuario1 a usuario2 pero tambien otra tabla muchos a muchos usuario1 a usuario1

Tambien debo crear una relacion muchos a muchos de usuario1 a usuario2

Comment: Y he pensado en poder relacionar las dos tablas resultantes a una tercera de ahi la pregunta si estaria correctamente diseñado, es decir ta tabla M:N resultante de usuario1 -> usuario2 con la otra tabla resultante de las tablas usuario1 -> usuario1


No se si he aclarado las dudas al respecto.